System.InvalidOperationException: OnStarting cannot be set because the response has already started
I am building plugins (projects) on NopCommerce (ASP.NET Core MVC project). I have two independent plugins (projects), one for exposing APIs and another for real-time chat support. For realtime chat I am using SignalR.
And this is the error call stack:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler: Error: Error when dispatching 'OnConnectedAsync' on hub.

System.InvalidOperationException: OnStarting cannot be set because the response has already started.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.OnStarting(Func`2 callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.InitializeHandlerAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Nop.Services.Authentication.CookieAuthenticationService.GetAuthenticatedCustomerAsync()
   at Nop.Plugin.API.Services.BearerTokenOrCookieAuthenticationService.GetAuthenticatedCustomerAsync()
   at Nop.Web.Framework.WebWorkContext.SetCurrentCustomerAsync(Customer customer) 
   at Nop.Web.Framework.WebWorkContext.GetCurrentCustomerAsync() 
   at Nop.Plugin.Widgets.RealTimeChat.Hubs.MessageHub.IsAuthenticated() in Documents\nopCommerce\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Widgets.RealTimeChat\Hubs\MessageHub.cs:line 63
   at Nop.Plugin.Widgets.RealTimeChat.Hubs.MessageHub.OnConnectedAsync() in nopCommerce\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Widgets.RealTimeChat\Hubs\MessageHub.cs:line 23
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.OnConnectedAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.OnConnectedAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler`1.RunHubAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint '/messageHub'

I can't solve this problem.
The following is my API plugin startup file
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{         
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, jwtBearerOptions =>
    {
        jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = //token validation parameter
        jwtBearerOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnChallenge = context =>
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = "Unauthorized access" });
                return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            }
        };
    });
    
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    AddAuthorizationPipeline(services);
 
    services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    });
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    });
    services.Configure<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    });

    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "nop commerce mobile api"
        });
    });

    services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigSwaggerOptions>();

    services.AddCors(opt =>
    {
        opt.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });
}
 
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var environment = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();

    var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite("api/token", "/token", true);
    app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy"); 

    app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")), a =>
    {
        a.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            await next();
        });

        // Authentication and authorization
        a.UseAuthentication();
        a.UseAuthorization();

        // Routing and endpoints
        a.UseRouting();
        a.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    });

    // Swagger configuration
    app.UseSwagger(options => options.RouteTemplate = "api/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json");
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.RoutePrefix = "api/swagger";
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/api/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Nop API v1");
    });
}  

And this is my Realtime chat plugin's startup file:
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    application.UseRouting();
    application.UseAuthorization();
    application.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>(RealTimeChatConstants.HubConnectionRoute);
    });
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddSignalR(r =>
    {
        r.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    });

    //register services
}

And this is the MessageHub from realtime chat plugin project:
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    // fields and ctor
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        if (!await IsAuthenticated())
        {
            return;
        }

        var currentCustomer = await _workContext.GetCurrentCustomerAsync();

        var existingUser = _connectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == currentCustomer.Id);

        if (existingUser == null)
        {
            _connectedUsers.Add(new UserConnection { ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId, UserId = currentCustomer.Id });
        }
        else
        {
            existingUser.ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        }

        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}

IsAuthenticated function call the method below:
public virtual async Task<Customer> GetAuthenticatedCustomerAsync()
{
    //try to get authenticated user identity
    var authenticateResult = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(NopAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);// getting error in this line
    if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded)
        return null;
    //logic to get customer

    return customer;
}

And calling from JS
var setUpConnection = function (hubUrl) {
    connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(hubUrl)
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
      .build();

    setUpSignalRConnection();
  }


What do you write in your IsAuthenticated method? For your MessageHub, any clients can trigger OnConnectedAsync, because your authentication is in the OnConnectedAsync method, which is wrong.

You should use [Authorize] to protect the signalr hub.

I have provided IsAuthenticated function. The error is from 'var authenticateResult' line

You should protect your Hub like below.
[Authorize] //Or [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="Your_Scheme")]
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
}

Reason
The clients will always connect to your MessageHub if they know the url, and the OnConnectedAsync method will always been triggered without [Authorize] attribute.
Try to delete below code and use correct way to protect you hubs.
 if (!await IsAuthenticated())
 {
    return;
 }


Through your solution, I could get rid of that error. But now I am facing 401 UnAuthorized error.

@SadikulHaqueSadi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-8.0#built-in-jwt-authentication

@SadikulHaqueSadi If you still don't know how to fix it , you can create a brand new sample which can reproduce the issue for me, then I will help you fix it.
